# Python recognise decimal input as string

Tags: python, python-3.x

## code:

```
import random

los = random.randint(1, 9)
print(los)
i = 0
strzal = 0
print(type(strzal))
while los != strzał or strzał == "exit":
       if i < 1: strzal = input("Wprowadź liczbę pomiędzy 1 a 9:    ")

       if i >= 1: strzal = input("Spróbuj jeszcze raz: ")
       if strzal != los: print("")
       i += 1
       print("i: ", i, " los: ") 
       print(type(los), los,  "strzał: ", type(strzał), strzał )
       print("Gratulacje! trafiłeś.")
```

and result on linux:

```
9
<class 'int'>
Wprowadź liczbę pomiędzy 1 a 9: 4
Nie trafiłeś. Spróbuj jeszcze raz bądż wprowadź "exit"
i:  1  los:  <class 'int'> 9 strzał:  <class 'str'> 4
Spróbuj jeszcze raz: 5
Nie trafiłeś. Spróbuj jeszcze raz bądż wprowadź "exit"
i:  2  los:  <class 'int'> 9 strzał:  <class 'str'> 5
Spróbuj jeszcze raz: exit
```

Comment: All input comes in as string. If you need to cast it to a different type:
`input("Wprowadź liczbę pomiędzy 1 a 9:    ")` should be 
`int(input("Wprowadź liczbę pomiędzy 1 a 9:    "))`

Answer (score 0):

You created an integer `los`.  You accept an input string `strzal`.  If you want to compare them, you need to cast one to the type of the other.  You probably want to make the input an integer:

```
zal = int(strzal)
if zal != los:
   print("")
```

Else, you could make your random number a string:

```
strlos = str(los)
if strzal != strlos:
   print("")
```